# Tensorflow while_loop how to return all intermediate values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the tensorflow documentation, we can easily get the last value of the loop:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
print(r.eval())
```

Result is

```
10
```

What would be a good way to get the intermediate values of the loop:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store these intermediate values in a tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
size = 10
values = tf.zeros(size, dtype=tf.int32)
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i, v: tf.less(i, size)
b = lambda i, v: [tf.add(i, 1), v + tf.one_hot(i, size, on_value=i)]
i_, values_ = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i, values])
print(i_.eval())
print(values_.eval())
```

Comment: what if each iteration in while loop update a 2D tensor, how do I construct a 3D tensor X such that X[i] is a 2D tensor that updated during the while loop?

Comment: @ElleryL I would suggest you ask a separate question, providing the expected output for a given input. Please let me know if you do!

Answer (score 1):

Use tf.TensorArray:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
N = 10
c = lambda i, _: tf.less_equal(i, N)
b = lambda i, ta: [tf.add(i, 1), ta.write(i, i)]
_, ta = tf.while_loop(c, b, [0, tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=N+1)])
print(ta.stack().eval())
```

or tf.scan (which is implemented using tf.while_loop and tf.TensorArray):

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
N = 10
fn = lambda a, x: x
elems = tf.constant(list(range(N+1)))
r = tf.scan(fn, elems)
print(r.eval())
```